# Replacing strings in one column with the details of another column in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I need to be able to replace values in one column from another column in a single dataframe

[image]

I imported this excel file as a pandas dataframe but how do I replace the values in left column (Freedom Town) with the values in the right column that come before the hyphen ( Fluent) in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: "before"? or after?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` to split on `' - '` then keep only the second part:

```
# replace colA & colB by real column names
df['colA'] = df['colB'].str.split(' - ').str[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values after `-`:

```
df['colA'] = df['colB'].str.extract('\s+-\s+(.*)', expand=False)
```